# Weird behaviour receiving a pdf content from a webservice nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, pdf, nusoap

I have created a function that calls a web service for contents of pdf file. The webservice works good.

I guess the problem comes when the file is too large.

I could fix this same problem on another server who had the same error throw the memory_limit and his php version is 5.4. The Nusoap version is the 0.9.5 and I'm using it via bundle from the composer.

This bundle is from `https://packagist.org/packages/econea/nusoap` and I'm using the v0.9.6.

In the server that I can't fix the error I use php 7.0. The Nusoap version is the 0.9.5 aswell in this server.

```
/**
 * @param string $docId
 * @return string
 */
public function getDocumentFromDocId(string $docId)
{
    $client = new \nusoap_client('http://'.$this->ip.'/arcdoc/WebServiceServer.php?wsdl', true);
    $response = $client->call('GetDoc', array(
        'xxxx1' => 'xxxxxx',
        'xxxx2' => base64_encode('xxxxx'),
        'xxxx3' => base64_encode("yyyyyyy"),
        'xxxx4' => base64_encode($docId)
    ));
    var_dump($response);
    return $response;
}
```

When I `var_dump()` the content response this response:

```
/var/www/html/project/src/AppBundle/Service/whatever.php:55:boolean false
```

If the file is bigger than 6-8M will be false the `$response` but if the file is less than 6-8M is not a problem.

So, I can say that the webservice works good in files with less size than 6-8M.

Any idea about why I'm not getting the answer?

I were testing to reduce the same pdf from `9M` to `6M` and works good, so it must be something about the size of the file. In my case seems to start to work bad at `7-9M`.

Comment: That sounds as if the SOAP service provider has some limitations of the filesize active - have you checked back with the provider?

Comment: I will check that but if it was this point I wouldn't receive all the pdf content until EOF when I use the print_r function, isn't it? It's so weird.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/nusoap/discussion/193578/thread/12965595/?limit=25#2a6d) and see if it helps you.

Comment: I'm using a bundle from composer and I don't want to overwrite this bundle to be able to update without problems via composer in the future but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$paramWSDLS = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-15',
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'exceptions' => false,
    'trace' => true,
    'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
);
$wsclient = new SoapClient('http://'.$this->ip.'/arcdoc/WebServiceServer.php?wsdl', $paramWSDLS );
$parametros = array(
   'xxxx' => 'xxxxxx',
   'xxxx2' => base64_encode('xxxxx2'),
   'xxxx3' => utf8_decode('xxxxx3'),
   'xxxx4' => utf8_decode('xxxxx4'),
   'showMask' => false
);
$response = $wsclient->__soapCall('GetDoc', $parametros );
```

Don't know why but using this SoapClient solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it could be related to allowed memory size in PHP. Just try to increase and test it. You can edit it either from `php.ini` or from `.htaccess` (not suggested).

`php.ini` example:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

`.htaccess` example:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

P.S. You can change `256` whatever memory you need.

Comment: Seems that is not the problem. I got 1024M in the php.ini's from apache2 and cli. But anyway the pdf it's like 9M. I also tried to add even a bigger number and "-1" in the memory limit. Nothing happens. So looks like to not be the answer I need.